# Доступ к базе данных в MS SQL через точку

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server

В некоторых источника в качестве строки подключения на источник данных используют не имя сервера (которое я ввожу при доступе к нему), а знак точки '.' и доступ открывается, но у меня не получается получить доступ к серверу таким образом и мне приходится вводить полное имя сервера. Что необходимо сделать, для доступа к базе данных точку

Comment: Точка означает текущую систему, т.е. сервер установлен на вашей же рабочей машине.

Comment: @Bulson Он у меня установлен на моей машине, но доступ к нему получить через точку я не могу, пробовал на компьютере знакомого, ситуация аналогичная

Comment: [Пример здесь](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/attach-a-database-file-on-connect-to-a-local-sql-server-express-instance/)

Comment: @Bulson ну так дело в том, что точка не представляет доступ к базе данных, хотя эта база данных у меня на компьютере и сервер тоже

Comment: Там есть нюансы, именованный инстанс сервера или не именованный. Вот допустимые [варианты](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188642.aspx#Anchor_0).

Comment: Ну точка указывает на то, что экземпляр сервера локален на компе... Выходит, мне нужно настроить базу данных, что бы она стала локальной

Comment: Какой именно sql server у вас установлен? Подозреваю, что LocalDB. Тогда вместо точки нужно писать `(LocalDB)`. Смотрите первый же пример [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#examples). Также пробуйте вариант `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`.

Comment: А у вашего знакомого, вполне вероятно, вообще нет никакой версии SqlServer.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, да у меня LocalDB